# Разобраться в коде - (библиотека itexstshap PDF)

Tags: c#

Непонятное место (для меня) в коде. Программа работает с PDF файлами. Вытаскивает информацию в CSV файл.

```
    class EUROFX_DBPDFFormatInfo_v4 : EUROFX_DBPDFFormatInfo_v3
{
    public override float CharSpacing { get { return 3.618f; } }
    public override int Version { get { return 4; } }

    protected override bool TryParsePageHeader(string line, out PdfPageHeadingInfo headerInfo)
    {
        var res =
            base.TryParsePageHeader(line, out headerInfo)
            && formatChange2015_07_07(headerInfo);
        return res;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Name + " v4, для DB с 8.07.2015";
        }
    }

    protected override string PositionFutMarkers
    {
        get
        {
            return
                /*
                |    DEC14    1.23960              1.24060    *1.23800     1.24060             1.24440  (   .8036) +     54     509    326872   463244 +    2827  1.39840B  1.23610
                |    SEP15              1.10660              1.10680         1.09270        1.09860  (   .9102) -    72         402    274988   352107 +    7026  1.39660B  1.04930A */
                "    |                 |                    |            |               ||          |          |      |           |         |        |           |         |";
            // Непонял этот момент кода. 
            //Припустил вероятность что таким образом показывается место в каких колонках нужный текст для извлечения. 
        }
    }
}
```

[Если нужно вот Парсер и документ откуда берется инфа](https://yadi.sk/d/az_9i76NiLK3w)

Comment: Никогда не работал с PDF документами... а сейчас нужно розобратся именно в этом моменте...Просто не понятно зачем использовать такое количество пробелов

Comment: 1) Данный класс наследован от `EUROFX_DBPDFFormatInfo_v3`, который явно также является пользовательским классов. 2) Свойство `PositionFutMarkers`, судя по ошибке в названии, также ВАШЕ. 3) Смотрите сами в коде базовых типов, где и как используется это свойство.

Comment: PositionFutMarkers используется и переводится Позиции На Фьючерс... Это то о чем я и говорил. "//Припустил вероятность что таким образом показывается место в каких колонках нужный текст для извлечения."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В базовом классе `DBPDFFormatInfo` поле `PositionFutMarkers` используется в методе `SplitPositionsFut`. Этот метод возвращает массив позиций символа `|` в строке `PositionFutMarkers` по средствам вызова метода `CalcPositions`. Полученный таким образом массив используется для разбивки входной внешней строки в методе:

```
public List<string> SplitFut(string line, string comod)
{
    var fields = SplitLine(line, comod != "EC/BP CROSS RT" ? this.SplitPositionsFut : this.SplitPositionsFut2);
        return fields;
}
```